# p:dataTable filtering doesn't work with template

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to create a filtering datatable with PrimeFaces framework.
My issue is that the datatable is displayed but filtering option doesn't work , help please !!

My page.xhtml looks like :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition>
        <h5>
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable var="student" value="#{studentWizard.students}" widgetVar="studentTable" emptyMessage="Aucun élève trouvé" id="tableStudent" filteredValue="#{studentWizard.filteredStudents}" >

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <h:outputText value="Chercher tous les champs:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="studentTable.filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Entrer le mot-clé"/>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column filterBy="#{student.studentCode}"  headerText="Code de l'élève" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{student.studentCode}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column filterBy="#{student.firstName}" headerText="Prénom" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{student.firstName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column filterBy="#{student.lastName}" headerText="Nom" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{student.lastName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Modifier" >
                        <p:commandButton value="Modifier" type="submit"  ajax="false"  icon="ui-icon-update"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </h5>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

and My Java Bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="studentWizard")
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class StudentWizard implements Serializable {

    public StudentWizard() {}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Student student;
    private List<Student> students;
    private List<Student> filteredStudents;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        students = getAllStudent();
    }

    public List<Student> getFilteredStudents() {
        return filteredStudents;
    }

    public void setFilteredStudents(List<Student> filteredStudents) {
        this.filteredStudents = filteredStudents;
    }

    @Autowired
    private StudentManager studentManager;

    public void setStudentManager(StudentManager studentManager) {
        this.studentManager = studentManager;
    }

    public Student getstudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public StudentManager getStudentManager() {
        return studentManager;
    }

    public void setstudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public void save() {
        studentManager.saveStudent(student);
        student = new Student();

    }

    public List<Student> getAllStudent() {
        return studentManager.getAllStudent();
    }

    public Student getStudentById(int id) {
        return studentManager.getStudentById(id);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

This is my home web page

```
<h:body>
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:100px;">
<p:layoutUnit position="center" size="400"  >
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:500px;">
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="244"  >
 <h5>       
<h:form>
   <p:menu toggleable="true">
     <p:submenu label="Eleves">
        <p:menuitem value="Nouvel élève" action="#{menuView.setSelectedItem(1)}"       update=":globalPanel"  />
        <p:menuitem value="Consultation" action="#{menuView.setSelectedItem(2)}" update=":globalPanel" />
    </p:submenu>
     <p:submenu label="Personnels">
     </p:submenu>
     <p:submenu label="Notes">
    </p:submenu>
     <p:submenu label="Caisses">
     </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Salaires">
     </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Référentiel">
     </p:submenu>
 </p:menu>
 </h:form>
</h5>
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
<h:panelGroup id ="globalPanel"  >
    <h:panelGroup id="inscriptionPanel" rendered="#{menuView.selectedItem == 1}" header="Inscription" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <ui:include src="/inscription.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>  
    <h:panelGroup id="testerPanel" rendered="#{menuView.selectedItem == 2}" header="Consultation" style="margin-bottom:20px"  >
    <ui:include src="/consul.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Comment: What PrimeFaces version do you happen to use? What does it mean by "*doesn't work*"? Why are those ugly annotations before the managed bean class? If you already happen to use Spring, why not choose that way only and stop misusing JSF by avoiding JSF related annotations?

Comment: I did not fix this `filteredValue="#   {studentWizard.filteredStudents}"`. There are spaces between `#` and `{`. If it is not a typo, please consider fixing it first.

Comment: No , there is no space between # and { ,actually  my code works,but just in the case  where I don't use template , but if I use <ui:include> it doesn't work !!!

Comment: I cannot say anything until you fix your bean management scheme. Make either Spring or JSF manage your beans. Thus you are not supposed to mix those annotations from both of these frameworks. In this current code snippets, you apparently assumed that the bean `StudentWizard` is a view scoped JSF managed bean which is essentially not. It is actually a "singleton" Spring bean (the default scope of a Spring bean). Those JSF annotations are simply avoided/ignored because that bean is being managed by Spring and JSF. To be continued.

Comment: because of this `<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>` in your JSF configuration file - `faces-config.xml`. This may or may not be the culprit of your actual problem but either way, you may want to fix it first.

Comment: There is a typo in this statement, "*that bean is being managed by Spring and JSF*". It has an incorrect meaning. I actually meant, "*that bean is being managed by Spring and **not** JSF*". i.e it is a  Spring managed bean and not a JSF managed bean. Apology.

Comment: Do you see a `<p:inputText>` on that `<p:dataTable>` column header, by the way? If it is already available there, can you see some JavaScript errors on the browser console on the `keyup` JavaScript event? It is also likely that the event itself is triggered for some unclear reason(s).

Comment: I have an error in my browser console it say :                                Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cw' of null     
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ab' of null

Comment: What are those `cw` and `ab`? In the current XHTML snippets, they cannot be found anywhere like `widgetVar`. Try looking into the generated HTML code. The browser console will be indicating a JavaScript file causing those errors with an appropriate line number. I hope that you will be able to get to the culprit using that line number.